# How to Copy file to network drive from OS X using java

Tags: java, macos

Hi I have a requirement where I have to copy file from my local eclipse workspace to some windows network drive. I am using the inbuilt java function where it was perfectly working fine in the windows system. but when I try the same code in MAC then it is not working. below are the source and destination file paths

```
source file path = /usr/documents/frameworkcode/tra_0001.dat 
destination file path = \\\\10.28.41.**\\d$\\test\\submit
```

I am using the below function from the FileUtils Class

```
FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(source, dest);
```

with this function the file was copying to destination directory from the windows machine but the same function is not copying files when I run it from Mac OS. instead it is creating a folder with the name (\\10.28.41.**\d$\test\submit) in the same workspace where the java code is running.

can any one please help/advice me how should I copy file to the network drive from OS X  . please let me know if there are any other alternative methods to copy the file to network drive

Please see the screenshot for the server which wanted to connect
[Network Drive Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goIAo.png)

Comment: The path delimiter on OSX like Linux is '/' not '\\'

Comment: Then it works??

Comment: i tried that too @SPlatten . can you please let me know how it should look like ? is it something like ////10.28.41.**/d$/test/submit  is it like this ??

Comment: Assuming that everything is on osX, just replace all occurances of '\\' with '/'.  Once / for each \\, so your path should read:  //10.28.41.**/d$/test/submit